# Error installing fast-logger for yesod setup, Ubuntu

Tags: haskell, ubuntu, cabal, yesod

I've been struggling to get Yesod running. I'm finally down to only one missing dependency, fast-logger, before I can build. However, when I run

```
cabal install fast-logger-2.2.3
```

I get the following error message:

```
System/Log/FastLogger/IO.hs:9:8:
    Could not find module `Blaze.ByteString.Builder.Internal.Types'
    It is a member of the hidden package `blaze-builder-0.3.3.4'.
    Perhaps you need to add `blaze-builder' to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed to install fast-logger-2.2.3
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
fast-logger-2.2.3 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

My first instinct was to install blaze-builder, in case it was missing. However, it seems to be installed just fine. Is this a problem with the fast-logger package?

Comment: have you install haskell platform? I see they are not recommending haskell platform but series of install steps instead. Have you tried this http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart ?

Comment: Blaze.ByteString.Builder.Internal.Types is not exposed by blaze-builder-0.3.3.4. However, it seems that fast-logger only depends on this internal module for versions of bytestring earlier than 0.10.2. The problem arises due to the fact that blaze-builder-0.3.3.4 depends on bytestring < 0.10, so you can't get the correct version of bytestring (0.10.2 or later) to make fast-logger build without getting a newer version of blaze-builder. The recommended course of action is to nuke your global package db and do this in a sandbox.

Comment: I did have the haskell platform installed. Cleaning it out and running the install steps again seems to have solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @DJTunafish: perhaps you should write this as a short answer (including the commands you ran), so that you can mark the question as solved and other users can find out how to solve this issue...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use the [Stackage LTS](http://www.stackage.org/lts) `cabal.config` file in all of your projects in order to eliminate most of the issues derived from version mismatches.

Nuke and re-initialize the cabal sandbox, drop the file into the project, `cabal install --only-dep -j` and you should have no trouble with it.